# Json remove whitespace before bracket PHP

Tags: php, json

I need to remove a whitespace before a the first bracket of a JSON file, my PHP code is like this:

```
$object = array_values($values);               
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($object, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: do you have any whitespace before the first `<?php`?

Comment: @Syscall that won't affect the output buffer

Comment: @Syscall i think he wants the whitespace, not the `[...]` removed

Comment: No, there is no spaces before <?php

Comment: Better post the complete code.

Comment: Is it actual whitespace - or perhaps a Byte Order Mark?

Comment: yes, it is a BOM, I have tried some methods to remove it before create the JSON but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it using the next code:

```
 <?php
 $data =file_get_contents('URL_to_JSON');
 $data = preg_replace( '/[\x{200B}-\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]/u', '', $data );
 $data = trim($data,chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0)); 
 echo $data;
 ?>
```

Using this method I have deleted the ZWNBSP before the brackets and now the JSON is correct.